# Which shell does rails use by default (because its not recognizing my ~/.bash_profile` aliases)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, bash, rc

Don't ask me too much about why I'm doing this, but I have a shell alias that opens up apple notes for me

```
alias notes='open /Applications/Notes.app'
```

This works from the command line if I put it in my ~/.bash_profile script.

When inside of a rails console however, and I run this:

```
`notes`
```

Rails returns a STDOUT saying the shell doesn't recognize the command, which it does if I ctrl+d out of the rails console and try it.

EDIT: Here's that error message, which now that I read it again is starting to seem like rails is actually interpreting this for some reason:

```
script/rails: No such file or directory - notes
```

So I've tried putting this alias code in: ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile and none of those seem to work.

And I'm just as curious about which shell rails uses as am I wanting to be able to do this tiny thing with the Notes app shortcut.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a ruby thing rather than a rails thing. The docs for [Kernel#exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60) has this to say about the "standard shell"

> The standard shell always means "/bin/sh" on Unix-like systems, same as ENV["RUBYSHELL"] (or ENV["COMSPEC"] on Windows NT series), and similar.